# Android Xamarin ViewCompat.GetTransitionName return null

Tags: android, xamarin

Добрый день.
Сабж постоянно возвращает null не пойму в чем секрет
Вот простенький пример:

```
var testView = new View(this);
testView.Id = 343;
Android.Support.V4.View.ViewCompat.SetTransitionName(testView, "test");
var s = Android.Support.V4.View.ViewCompat.GetTransitionName(testView);
```

Ожидаю увидеть s == "test" но она null

Comment: на какой версии Android?

Comment: Версия андроида 4.4.2